# `docker-compose up` creating containers under one parent folder/ directory in docker desktop app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have this docker-compose.yml. When I am running command `docker-compose up` the containers are created properly but under one parent folder of docker desktop. I do not want my containers to be under that parent folder. I want them free containers at root. How to achieve it?

Providing image 1 where my docker-compose.yml present
[image]

Providing image 3 of my docker desktop
[image]

Comment: That's just how Docker Desktop chooses to display them, other tools (e.g. `docker ps`) _do_ show them all in a single list.

Comment: Containers don't have folders.  If you use CLI tools like `docker ps`, there's just a flat listing.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `docker-compose` command creates the containers under the project name you are in. Use `docker-compose -p . up`, where `-p` is the project name. You can use `--project-name` in stead to specify it. It uses `.` to told him to create in the actual directory. Replace it with the path you want. Finally I imagine you know that `up` is for create and run the contanier.

Hope this can help you :)